# Surface area by the revolution of cycloid

Tags: calculus, integration

How to find the surface area of the solid generated by the revolution of the cycloid about $x$-axis?

I  know the formula to find out the surface area but
I'm getting the point that in the formula why we take the integration limit as 0 to $2\pi$.

Please, help me out!

Answer (score 3):

The parametric equation of the [cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid) is 
$$x(t)=r(t-\sin t) \, \quad  y(t)=r(1-\cos t) \quad \mbox{for $t\in[0,2\pi]$.}$$
Its surface of revolution around the $x$-axis is given by
$$S:=2\pi \int_0^{2\pi}y(t) \sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}dt.$$
Then
$$x'(t)=r(1-\cos t) \ , \  y'(t)=r\sin t \implies
x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2=2r^2(1-\cos t)=4r^2\sin^2(t/2)
$$
and we find that 
$$
\begin{align}
S&=2\pi \int_0^{2\pi}r(1-\cos t) \cdot 2r\sin(t/2)dt
=8\pi r^2\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^3(t/2)dt\\
&=16\pi r^2\int_0^{\pi}\sin^3(s)ds
=16\pi r^2\int_0^{\pi}(1-\cos^2(s))d(-\cos(s))\\
&=16\pi r^2\left[\cos(s)-\frac{1}{3}\cos^3(s)\right]_{\pi}^0=\frac{64\pi r^2}{3}.
\end{align}$$